# dispatch not defined in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm looking at the async redux example here:

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/async/src/containers/App.js

If I add the following:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Then dispatch is no longer defined in componentDidMount. Why is this? How can I access dispatch here while using mapDispatchToProps?

Answer (score 2):

The `connect` function automatically passes `dispatch` to your `props` if **you do not specify** a `mapDispatchToProps` function. With that in mind:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

And it should work. [You can read more about the react-redux bindings in the docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to call dispatch from the componentDidMount as a function in the this.props (which I don't recommend, check how redux works and create the action creators that you need). Even so, to achieve that you can do that:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return { dispatch };
}
```

That creates a dispatch property that is the dispatch function itself.
Still, don't do that on a real use case and keep reading about redux action.creators.

Answer (score 1):

Following the given example, you pass `mapDispatchToProps` to `connect` like this

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onClick: nextReddit => {
      dispatch(selectReddit(nextReddit));
    }
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Component `App` will then be empowered with a prop `onClick` which is used as below.

```
handleChange = nextReddit => {
  this.props.onClick(nextReddit)
}

render() {
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <Picker value={selectedReddit}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            options={[ 'reactjs', 'frontend' ]} />
    ...
  );
}
```